# Reading json data in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

Im currently in the process of making a mobile application to go with my web app with a django backend.

I make a request to the server in swift then I get back this response

```
[{"model": "webapp.comment", "pk": 73, "fields": {"commentDescription": "hello there", "owner": 25, "postId": 78}},

{"model": "webapp.comment", "pk": 72, "fields": {"commentDescription": "well hi", "owner": 25, "postId": 78}}]
```

How do I then loop through and access these values like `commentDescription` , `owner` , `pk` and use them in my mobile application using swift as strings. I've tried using *Gloss* to read it but i'm still lost.

Answer (score 2):

Using  [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) library

```
import SwiftyJSON

let jsonData = JSON(data:data) // data is your NSData JSON response
for (_,item):(String, JSON) in jsonData { //loop through your json objects
  print(item["model"].stringValue)
  print(item["pk"].intValue) 
  print(item["fields"][commentDescription].stringValue)
  print(item["fields"]["owner"].stringValue)
  print(item["fields"]["postId"].intValue)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
guard let stringData = JSONSTRING.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding,
            allowLossyConversion: false) else { return }

        do {
            if let dict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(stringData,
                options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
 } catch {
            logAndError("Got unknown error from server")
        }
```